# posix_openpt() - error - Cant access tty, job control turned off

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm using a psuedo terminal, /bin/sh -i, by calling normal commands for posix_openpty() then fork(), in language C.

When I run from command line GUI terminal like this

```
$ ./MyTerminal
```

or

```
$ sudo ./MyTerminal
```

or as root like this

```
# ./MyTerminal
```

all works very good and as expected, no problems.

However, when I make a systemd service file like this, it works fine

```
[Service]
User=root
```

But when I try to get systemd to run it as normal user like this

```
[Service]
User=debian
```

THe first output for /bin/sh -i is

```
/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off $
```

And the terminal does not really work.

When I run /bin/bash, fork() w/posix_openpty() is returns me this, but the terminal generally works ok

```
 bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device 
 bash: no job control in this shell
```

Is such a weird prolem because when running outside of systemd everything works perfect. I see this problem in 1 other question but no clear solution. So what I have to change to make systemd run my file perfectly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stuff running under `systemd` does not have a controlling terminal, I'd wager (actually, I'd almost guarantee it...). If you want it to run under `systemd`, change the code that assumes that a terminal exists - either just don't attempt to use the terminal at all, or at least check for it's existence before you try to manipulate it...

Comment: Thanks, but I need the terminal, and yes I check for it's existence in a variety of ways - it exists, and the problem is when not running as root. Yes, even when it runs it behaves differently. Is there any other (more or less) cross platform way to start a binary that depends on a terminal?

Comment: What do you get with (as root) `su -c ./MyTerminal debian`?

Comment: duplicate of ["bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off” error when running shellcode"](https://superuser.com/a/1715415/951886)